# jquery each - function from another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, gallery

I have a bit of a trouble with jQuery .each() function (still a beginner). What I would like to achieve is to have multiple image sliders on the website, but the sliders scripts I found are mostly using a `<div id="slides">` to work and I'd like to make it like `<div class="slides">` with the `.each` method. Of course every script is included in the `HTML` file, so that can't be the problem.

The initialization is like this in jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
      });
    });
  </script>
```

And I've wrote this in my scrits.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slides').each(slidejs({
        width: xxx,
        height: yyy
    });
});
```

With this script in, the whole thing is dead, no other scripts are working :/
Can You please help me with this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @SridharR you would not suggest that if one needs 20+ of them :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes right then use each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've understood your point. The easiest way would be to add a common class name (instead of id) to each slider. For example :

```
<div id="slides1" class="slides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
  </div>

<div id="slides2" class="slides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">

  </div>

<div id="slides3" class="slides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">

  </div>
```

Then call it this way (notice the '.' instead of '#') :

```
 $(".slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
      });
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I've just tested it. (Assuming you are using the jQuery plugin slidesJS)

Comment: Just tried your solution too, It's a great idea, why didn't I think about it, but it still doesn't want to work :(#

Comment: Thanks for the help! @adeneo pointed out the obvious for me too, so, special thanks to you too!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an anonymous function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slides').each(function() {
            $(this).slidejs({
                width: xxx,
                height: yyy
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: isn't this the same as just `$(".slides").slidesjs({` ?

Comment: adeneo: I've tried it, all the other scripts are working, but the slider isn't :( what could cause that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - It is if the plugin uses `return this.each(function() {...` etc. If the plugin doesn't, and only works with a single element, it's not the same.

Comment: @adeneo hm, than looks like the plugin does not recognizes collections to init apply a `new` to each.

Comment: @sikitomi - You're aware that you're using two different plugin names, in the first code it's `slidesjs`, in the second it's `slidejs` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Had to look more closely, as using an each loop should work, even if the plugin doesn't take a collection of elements, so something else must be wrong, and using the wrong name would do it. Having my coffee now ;). ..

Comment: @adeneo Good eyes! :) But it wasn't the problem, I've changed it and it just doesn't wanna work sitll. I even copied the code as-is from the example and that doesn't want to work either! Smthing else is bad, but the script is included, jquery is included too, so I'm totally busted on this one now :(

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan u can check it at http://sikitomi.hopto.org/printpod It's under the mug section.

Comment: Did you notice the javascript actually being outputted on your site, and that you're missing script tags ?